# What kind of data should be shared between parent and child components in Angular?

Tags: angular

https://medium.com/@agoiabeladeyemi/introduction-to-angular-component-138e9c24b54a

This link talks about using @Input and @Output decorators to share data between parent and child components. Here parent component is `app.module.ts` and the components which the users make are child components.

I am making a blog application in which I have a main component which shows a list of blogs and another component which allows us to edit one blog at a time.
I can understand about sharing data among sibling components.

In what case we would be requiring sharing data between `app.module.ts` and a child component. Till now I have used `app.module.ts` only for writing import statements and declaring child components.

What kind of data should be shared between parent and child components in Angular?

Comment: whatever you need to solve particular problem

Comment: @Xesenix Please give an example of one particular problem. That'll give me an idea.

Comment: you are creating component that somehow formats displaying of its children, other you are creating data source for underlying components, more specific ones for those two display modal window or notification or data grid data source requesting something from server or some drag and drop behaviour controller. And almost anything you can think of can either use input or dependency injection context.

Answer (score 2):

@Input() properties can have any type, such as number, string, boolean, or object. Check this [article](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inputs-outputs). just put as binding

```
<child-component data="{{data}}"></child-component>
```

you can read like

```
@Input data:string;

@Input data:number;

@Input data:ObjectName;
```

to choose which you want depends on your child component's needs. There is no rule that you should send string or bool or number.

For example If your child components need more than one variable, you can send one input and send object rather than using more than one inputs for each needed variable.

or in your child components you will need to check condition  and show hide something your sending bool is better rather than to send string like 'true'.

So you should choose shared data depends on how you need in child component

Comment: My question isn't about knowing syntax. I want to know what should be passed between parent and child in real life applications. For example in a blog application, what can be passed between parent and child?

Comment: I understood now and explained.